# Is it possible to return blank strings in .values() from a Django queryset?

Tags: python, django

In Django, if I have 2 models:

```py
class MyModelA(models.Model):
    column_1 = ...
    column_2 = ...
    column_3 = ...

class MyModelB(models.Model):
    column_1 = ...
    column_2 = ...
    column_3 = ...
    column_4 = ...
    column_5 = ...
```

I need to use `union` to combine the results in these, but they don't have the same number of columns. For the extra columns, I just need `MyModelA` to return blank strings.

Is it possible to do something like this?

```py
MyModelA.objects.values("column_1", Value(""), Value(""), "column_2", "column_3").union(
    MyModelB.objects.values("column_1", "column_2", "column_3", "column_4", "column_5")
)
```

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#union) on `union`

> Passing different models works as long as the SELECT list is the same in all QuerySets (at least the types, **the names don’t matter as long as the types are in the same order**)

This means I'm basically trying to map:

```
MyModelA.column_1 --> MyModelB.column_1
""                --> MyModelB.column_2
""                --> MyModelB.column_3
MyModelA.column_2 --> MyModelB.column_4
MyModelA.column_3 --> MyModelB.column_5
```

Using `Value("")` as above doesn't work however. Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from django.db.models import F, Value

MyModelA.objects.values("column_1", column_2=Value(""), column_3=Value(""), column_4=F("column_2"), column_5=F("column_3")).union(
    MyModelB.objects.values("column_1", "column_2", "column_3", "column_4", "column_5")
)
```

You might not even need `F` as names might not clash in your case with real column names.

Comment: I can't believe how simple the solution ended up being. This saved me a ton of digging. Thanks!